# pgsql parse string to get a string after certain position

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table column that has data like

```
NA_PTR_51000_LAT_CO-BOGOTA_S_A
NA_PTR_51000_LAT_COL_M_A
NA_PTR_51000_LAT_COL_S_A
NA_PTR_51000_LAT_COL_S_B
NA_PTR_51000_LAT_MX-MC_L_A
NA_PTR_51000_LAT_MX-MTY_M_A
```

I want to parse each column value so that I get the values in column_B. Thank you.

```
    COLUMN_A                        COLUMN_B

    NA_PTR_51000_LAT_CO-BOGOTA_S_A  CO-BOGOTA
    NA_PTR_51000_LAT_COL_M_A        COL
    NA_PTR_51000_LAT_COL_S_A        COL
    NA_PTR_51000_LAT_COL_S_B        COL
    NA_PTR_51000_LAT_MX-MC_L_A      MX-MC
    NA_PTR_51000_LAT_MX-MTY_M_A     MX-MTY
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure of the Postgresql and I can't get SQL fiddle to accept the schema build...

substring and length may vary...

```
Select Column_A, substr(columN_A,18,length(columN_A)-17-4) from tableName
```

Ok how about this then:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ad0dd/56/0

```
Select column_A, b
from (
  Select Column_A, b, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY column_A) AS k
  FROM (
    SELECT Column_A
           , regexp_split_to_table(Column_A, '_') b
    FROM test
       ) I 
     ) X
Where k%7=5
```

Inside out:
Inner most select simply splits the data into multiple rows on _
middle select adds a row number so that we can use the use the mod operator to find all occurances of a 5th remainder.

This ASSUMES that the section of data you're after is always the 5th segment AND that there are always 7 segments...

Comment: Thanks xQbert. It worked. Initially I thought of building using substr but with my limited knowledge, couldn't seem to figure out how can I dynamically find the position of fourth underscore. I don't want to hard code 18, 17, 4 in the above code. Any idea will be appreciated. Thanks again.

Comment: So what are the rules which denote when you want vs don't want data?  I hardcoded 18 because in the example NA_PTR_51000_LAT_ is always 18.  Do the _ denote a new set of data so that after the 4th _ you would be wanting data up to the next _? if so we can do that...

Comment: You are awesome! Liked the approach. its simple, self explanatory, can be used to get any characters after any underscore! whohooo! Thanks a looooot! You are a rockstar!

Comment: I'll admit I'm a little worried about how the row numbers are assigned.  I'm not positve it will work in 100% of the cases as I don't know what order is assigned to to the subtable I.  In all the tests I ran I got the desired results, but It seems to me that the engine could do something I don't want since I wasn't able to specify an order by.  I assume the regexp_Split will always list them in the order they occur within the split.  But *shrug* this seemed close enough :D

Comment: Hi xQbert, I fiddled and found that when I added another column with 7 segments and trying to get 5th one, it gave me different result than expected. This is what I inserted , built schema and ran sql insert into test (Column_A) values ('AM_CE_37_LAT_MEX-MC_SM_A');

Answer (score 0):

Use [regexp_matches()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-string.html) with a search pattern like 'NA_PTR_51000_LAT_(.+)_'

This should return everything after NA_PTR_51000_LAT_ before the next underscore, which would match the pattern you are looking for.

Comment: Ty for your suggestion. I m new to regex expressions. I tried running query on what you said SELECT regexp_matches('NA_PTR_51000_LAT_CO-BOGOTA_S_A', 'NA_PTR_51000_LAT_(.+)_') which gave me {CO-BOGOTA_S}. could you please explain a little bit? thanks.

Comment: Basically regexp, or regular expressions are a way of picking out a part of a document by identifying a consistent pattern. Here the pattern is NA_PTR_51000_LAT_<stuff you want here>_<stuff you don't care about> [here is the section of the manual that tells you how to construct regexp inside postgres](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-matching.html). What the pattern I wrote is supposed to do is find NA...LAT_ take every character in between that and the next underscore and return it (the bit you want). Looks like it almost worked, try NA...LAT_(.+)(backslash char)_ instead

Comment: Thanks again for giving me some insights into regular expressions. I did run SELECT regexp_matches('NA_PTR_51000_LAT_CO-BOGOTA_S_A', 'NA_PTR_51000_LAT_(.+)\_') and got {CO-BOGOTA_S}. With RE being 'new' to me, it will take long time to figure out what is to be changed to just get CO-BOGOTA. On the same note, how can we dynamically know NA_PTR_51000_LAT_ part in 'NA_PTR_51000_LAT_(.+)\_'? Thanks again.

Comment: There has to be some point of similarity for the same RE to pick out data, if you identify that pattern, you next need to use the syntax I linked (or googling the general idea of the RE you want to create for a start) to create an expression that works... I found it to be largely a trial and error process :) If you don't have 1 general pattern, but a number of different patterns, you will need a RE for each pattern.